# self deleting instance

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a class call `del()` for some instances under some condition? Or turn self into None?

```
    class T:
        def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
            condition=check_condition(arg1,arg2)
            if not condition:
               do_something(arg1)
            else:
               del(self) #or self=None or return None
```

I need to do something like this to be sure that will never exist a kind of instance.

Comment: ... `raise Exception()` ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989042/preventing-a-class-from-direct-instantiation-in-python) has a bunch of answers that can help

Comment: Good idea Izkata. My problem was: the class T is a value-object that contains their own validation method. In not-valid cases, the object should not be initialized (and destroyed, if possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need do something like this to be sure that will never exist a kind of instance.

If you simply want to prevent the creation of such an instance, raise an exception in `__init__()` whenever the condition is satisfied.

This is standard protocol for signalling constructor failures. For further discussion, see [Python: is it bad form to raise exceptions within __init__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507082/python-is-it-bad-form-to-raise-exceptions-within-init)

Answer (score 3):

Look into [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). You should be able to detect the condition you care about and return `None`. As @lzkata mentions in the comments, raising an `Exception` is probably a better approach, though.

Comment: Do this.  It's better to not create the instance in the first place than to clean it up in `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

You can raise an exception as suggested in comments. You can implement `__new__`. Also you can make some factory class, like

```
class TFactory:
    def createT(self, arg1, arg2):
        condition=check_condition(arg1,arg2)
        if not condition:
           return do_something(arg1)
        else:
           return None
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call del self. it works just fine, but you should know that all it's doing is deleting the reference to an instance, named "self" in the **init** method.

In python, objects exist as long as there is a reference to them somewhere.

If you want the object to never exist under certain conditions, then do not ever attempt to create an instance under those conditions, outside of **init** where you are creating the object.

Also, you could define a helpful function in this class to return whether those conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The class constructor is intended to really construct an instance of its class and not fail half-silently by just not constructing an instance and returning None. Nobody would expect that behaviour.

Rather use a factory function.

```
class Test(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        if ok(): return cls()
        else: return None
```

Comment: I agree that returning None is never a good idea -- especially since `__init__()` doesn't have a return value anyway. ;-)