# How can I stop a Python class with no abstract methods from being instantiated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I have the following code:

```
class Category(abc.ABC):
    foo = {"bar"}
```

Despite inheriting from `abc.ABC`, I can instantiate a `Category` just fine:

```
>>> a = Category()
>>>
```

whereas I would expect it to raise an error like the following.

```
>>> class Foo(abc.ABC):
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def bar(self):
...         return "baz"
... 
>>> f = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Foo with abstract methods bar
>>>
```

It seems that this is because `Category` has no abstract methods. How can I ensure that trying to instantiate `Category` will raise an exception?

Comment: Why do you need an exception? Is this just for understanding?

Comment: What you're doing seems odd to me, you may be going down a bad path. But if you're sure it's what you want, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7990308/2337736

Comment: Yes, this is a fairly bad way to approach it - I'm sure I'll rewrite this many times (it's a small personal project), so more as a point of interest than anything serious.

Comment: So, an ABC is a way of defining an interface, but if it doesn't have any methods, it's not really an interface, eh? I guess I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```python
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta

class Category(ABC):
    foo = {"bar"}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if (cls.__base__ is ABC or cls.__class__ is ABCMeta):
            raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate abstract class {cls}")
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

This could also be helpful in case if you want to share this behavior between a few related abstract classes. For instance:

```python
class CategoryGroup(ABC):
    baz = {"qux"}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if (cls.__base__ is ABC or cls.__class__ is ABCMeta):
            raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate {cls.__name__}")
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class Category(CategoryGroup, ABC):
    foo = {"bar"}
```

In the example above, you would get a TypeError if you tried to create `Category` or `CategoryGroup` objects, as shown below:

```
>>> CategoryGroup()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __new__
TypeError: Can't instantiate CategoryGroup
>>> Category()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __new__
TypeError: Can't instantiate Category
>>> Category.__base__
<class '__main__.CategoryGroup'>
```